# Crashing when saving local data with sqlite on Xamarin

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on a Xamarin Forms android app and I am getting the following error that I don't understand.

```
  native: pc 0000000000047696  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_mutex_lock+1)
  native: pc 0000000000010087  /data/app/pwnedpasswords.pwnedpasswords-1/lib/arm/libe_sqlite3.so (sqlite3_finalize+26)
  native: pc 000000000000808c  <anonymous:d2a07000>
```

When I debug via visual studio I am not getting any errors, however when I run from my phone I do.

The code I think is causing it is as follows:

```
var saveddata = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "data.db3"));
saveddata.CreateTable<HIBP>();
saveddata.Insert(data);
```

I suspect my app is trying to save duplicate data which it doesn't like and crashing. Any ideas of how to verify and fix this?

Comment: Have you given the permission to read/write external storage in the Android Manifest file ?

Comment: What's the error message you get when running on the phone?

Comment: app crashes out and restarts so no error displayed on phone

Comment: have you tried using a try/catch to catch the exception causing the crash?